# ASP.NET MVC 3 x86 project fails to compile on TFS Build server 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, x86, tfsbuild

I try to set up a build definition for an x86 ASP.NET MVC 3 project on TFS Build server 2012. The project compiles perfectly on a local machine without warning (no warning for x86 / MSIL mismatch).

When I set up a build definition, and run the build, I get this error :

> ASPNETCOMPILER: Could not load file or assembly 'ASSEMBLY_NAME' or one
>   of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.

I tried to have an x86 platform configuration at solution level to be able to set the "Configuration to Build" Settings in the build definition to `x86|Release` without success.

I don't see any option in the compilation section of the web.config that could let me specify a platform.

It is possible to set up a build definition that would let me build x86 ASP.NET MVC3 projects on TFS Build server 2012 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to drop the view compilation in the project, as it doesn't seem to be supported at the moment by the build server :

```
 <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
```

You can give a different value for this setting per configuration, if you want to keep building them locally in debug for example.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you do not have the required components on the Build Server.

While it is prudent to have all of the pieces that you can referenced through NuGet or checked into Version Control in a known location there are always things that are required on the build server that go beyond that.

**The test: Can you log into the Build Server, open your Solution in Visual Studio and successfully build it there?**

If not I would suggest that you use the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and select MVC 3 in addition to any other components that you might need. In essence your build server should be setup just like your development workstation. And yes, while it would be awesome not to have to that does include Visual Studio. Helpfully if you are operating within the bounds of MSDN there is no additional licence requirement for installing it here in addition to your developer workstation. Indeed it goes a little further and states that if you own one licence for Ultimate you can install it and everyone can send builds to the build server wherever version of MSDN they are licensed for...

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the solution builds without error or warning on the build server. The issue comes from MvcBuildViews that I set to true. It seems it's not supported by the build server compiler. It might be linked to [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157362/asp-net-mvc-3-0-build-views-as-64-bit)

Comment: The "build server compiler" is the same one that is in Visual Studio. In fact the build server calls the exact same instance as Visual Studio does locally. There are some differences in the parameters that are passed in which often causes issues, but other than that...